# How to add Order print for magento admin? Magento>sales>orders>orderprint

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I need to know a way of adding print order feature to magento admin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this [extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/admin-order-printing-extension.html). I didnt tested it. So manually install it. Copy paste its  extension key and download [here](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php).

*Edit: It seems the developer deleted the above given extension now. There is an another extension for the same. But Not Free as earlier !!! Check it out [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/print-orders-from-admin-1730.html) !*

Comment: edit 'app/code/local/Nastnet/OrderPrint/Block/Sales/Order/View.php'.
On line 8, replace '*/sales_order/print' with 'html/sales_order/print'. This worked for me in order to fix the 404 url error when printing the order.

Comment: Use this to download magento extensions http://www.tangkoko.com/direct-download-magento-extension/